# Get reviewer object tied to specific revision (C#, MSWord, VSTO)

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I have a Word ribbon written in C#. I'm trying to code a set of buttons that will hide the revisions made by a given reviewer. I want to base that on the text the user has selected (i.e., if their cursor is in a revision made by Author X and they click the Hide button, all Author X's changes will be hidden).

I can get the list of revisions in the selection, but [the Revision interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.revision_members.aspx) only seems to expose the author's name.

I can get a list of reviewers in the document, but [the Reviewer interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.reviewer_members.aspx) doesn't seem to provide a way to tie it to the author's name.

Is there truly no way to link a specific Revision object to a specific Reviewer object? Obviously there's some internal way because you can hide revisions by reviewer in the Review tab.

Is there some other way of accomplishing this that I'm not seeing?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too late but I stumbled upon your post while looking for something similar. you can access a reviewer based on the author name by passing the author string instead of an Id into the reviewers collection

```
var author = "HiddenAuthor";

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Reviewers[author].Visible = false;
```